# django - get field via verbose name

Tags: django, field

suppose I have this field in `Foo` model

```
field1 = CharField(max_length=10, verbose_name='Bar')
```

Is there a way to return `field1` via its `verbose_name`?

Here is my visualization for it but it throws a `TypeError`

```
Foo._meta.get_field(verbose_name='Bar')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually filter on these, and return the first one that matches:

```
my_field = next(
    field for field in Foo._meta.get_fields() if field.verbose_name='Bar'
)
```

This will raise a [**`StopIteration`**](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/exceptions.html#StopIteration) in case no such field exists.

It is possible that there are **multiple such fields**. We can for example generate a list of these fields with a similar *list comprehension*:

```
all_bar_fields = [
    field for field in Foo._meta.get_fields() if field.verbose_name='Bar'
]
```